# Database and code approach for auto generated invoices

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Let's say I manage a Domain name site where I sell domain names and their hosting.

Each of my clients will have a cost:

**Domain name:** example.com

**Cost:** 100.00 dollars

**Duration:** 1 year

What I want to do in my program, is to auto generate an invoice when their domain name is about to expire.

I already have the following approach:

**Recurring invoice table:**

```
Recurring_Invoices
 InvoiceID[ID]
 domain_name[VARCHAR]
 Price[Double]
 Last_Invoice_Date[DATETIME]
 Is_Recurring[BYTE]     
 Next_Invoice_Date[DATETIME]
```

My approach on my code level is the following:

Every time my program gets launched, I will check if there are invoices to be generated for that month. In pseudo code I will do:

```
void getRecurringInvoices()
{
   //Select the invoices WHERE Is_Recurring = 1
}

foreach (Invoice i in RecurringInvoices)
{
  // Get the month of Next_Invoice_Date
  if(Month of Next_Invoice_Date == DateTime.Now.Month)
  {
     //this is an invoice that needs to be generated + Next Invoice Date needs 
     to be prolonged with 1 year
}
```

I wanted to ask if this is approach is OK. My only concern with this one is that if my program doesn't get run for 1 month, recurring invoices of that month won't be generated.

That's why I'm still having my doubts off this approach.

What could I do to optimize this process?

Comment: If you do it this way, you should probably add a last invoice generation date to know if anyone was missed for some reason.

Comment: With this solution someone could get an invoice that is already overdue when they get it. Don’t you have some batch/cron functionality on your server or included in the DB server?

Comment: @xDJR1875 , i already have that under `Last_Invoice_date`

@JoakimDanielson , normally with this solution, invoices are sent on the month-1 where the domain gets expired so normally they won't be overdue. i want to use only self made code and not depend on batch/cron functionalities.

Comment: If your only concern is if it doesn't get ran one month, then since you have the Last_Invoice_date, you could key off that to make sure invoices get ran at the next available time. So that being your only issue, you should be fine. Being a sql person, I would tend to create a job that would run at pre-defined time each week/mth that would check for invoices that need to be ran. That would isolate the business logic within the db and not spread out the business logic into a separate location.